# Разница в вызове функции класса до и после загрузки контента в активити android?

Tags: android, content

В каждой активити есть вызов функции:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
```

я так понимаю она отвечает за установку разметки, но проблема в том что я хочу до того как разметка расставится и установится обратится к серверу в за кое-какими данными и уже потом при наличии этих данных устанавливать разметку уже с этими данными. Я пробовал вызов функции сделать до `setContentView` но почему-то так получается что мои `textView` выводят null. Пробовал сделать вызов в onStart() но так вообще ничего не работает. Не могу понять как по-нормальному что-бы был сначала вызов а потом уже была разметка с данными с сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот метод **создаёт** вью-элементы по макету и добавляет их в окно приложения.
До выполнения метода вью не существуют и, естественно, найти их и вставить в них данные невозможно.
Выполняется он не настолько долго, чтобы данные из сети успели за это время загрузится - поэтому не стоит овчинка выделки.

Comment: хм... что же делать тогда? может тогда закинуть условие - если запрос прошел, то вызывать этот метод?

Comment: У Вас вариант разметки зависит от результата запроса или в чём проблема?

Comment: нет, просто мне нужно заполнить textView информацией из ответа запроса,  а без самого запроса там висит null. и это не красиво

Comment: Повесьте туда что-то красивое, а когда запрос пройдёт смените на полезное. Запрос, в зависимости от состояния сети может повиснуть и надолго. И если Вы будете держать вывод UI до его окончания будет ощущение "зависания, тормознутости и т.п." - это тоже некрасиво и юзер может не дождаться, а пойти поставить Вам пол звезды в маркет)))

Comment: а вот это кстати хорошая идея, спасибо